# Making the unnumbered Bibliography chapter in memoir into a numbered chapter

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, numbering, memoir, chapters

My supervisor has told me my references section needs to be numbered. However, I do not know how to make that happen. I read somewhere about redefining the `\printbibliography` command within the memoir.cls file, but I don't know where to find this file.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just use `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are apparently using `biblatex`, so you can simply use  `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]`